# Arrow lost inside a loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, clip

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \draw[gray!20,dashed] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
        \draw[-latex] (-4.2,0)--(4.3,0) node[right] () {\footnotesize $x$};
        \foreach \i in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
            \draw (\i,-0)--(\i,-0.1) node[below] () {\footnotesize \i};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-4.2)--(0,4.3) node[above] () {\footnotesize $y$};
        \foreach \i in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
            \draw (0,\i)--(-.1,\i) node[left] () {\footnotesize \i};
        \draw (-.2,-.2) node () {\footnotesize $O$};
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) circle(4);
            \foreach \a in {45,135,225,315}{
            \draw[cyan,fill] plot[domain=-2:2,smooth,rotate=\a] (\x,{\x*\x+1});
            \draw[-latex,magenta,line width=2pt,rotate=\a] (1,0)--(4,0);
            }
        \end{scope}
        \draw[magenta] (0,0) circle(1);
        \draw[magenta] (0,0) circle(4);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

and this output:

[image]

Why I lost the first magenta arrow?

**EDIT** If I adopt the Jasper's suggestion and I try to draw the arrow outside the scope:

```
\draw[-latex,magenta,line width=2pt] (.707,.707)--(2.828,2.828);
```

I have the arrow! But that is not a good way to resolve the problem. We have a problem, perhaps, in the `tikz foreach` loop.

Comment: Maybe it is clipped away. Try to draw it outside the clipped scope.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht No, its well inside the clip, like all others arrows.

Comment: For the arrow \a=45 is ignored.

Comment: What happens when you change the order in `{45,135,225,315}` is it always the first element that disappears?

Comment: @albert Yes, for this order {135,225,315,45} the first arrow is not drawn. But the parabola it is.

Comment: @JasperHabicht  The only portion that could be outside the clipping area is the end of arrow, the remaining one is always inside. Also for others values of \a we can have problems of rounding. Furthemore we must have the same problems in the albert approach.

Comment: With \draw[cyan,fill] plot[domain=-2:2,smooth,rotate=-90+\a] (\x,{\x*\x+1}); it work fine

Comment: You are right. The reason is in fact that for 45 degrees, the plot is drawn above the arrow. You can see this, when you set opacity=0.5. The reason is that the arrows are rotated by 90 degrees in respect to the plot.

Comment: @pascal974 No, the last parabola is without arrow.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro for me it'Ok see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last area in the loop is drawn on top of the first arrow. This is probably what you want:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray!20, dashed] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
\draw[-latex] (-4.2,0)--(4.3,0) node[right]{\footnotesize $x$};
\foreach \i in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
\draw (\i,-0)--(\i,-0.1) node[below]{\footnotesize \i};
\draw[-latex] (0,-4.2)--(0,4.3) node[above]{\footnotesize $y$};
\foreach \i in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
\draw (0,\i)--(-.1,\i) node[left]{\footnotesize \i};
\draw (-.2,-.2) node{\footnotesize $O$};
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) circle(4);
\foreach \a in {45,135,225,315}{
\fill[cyan] plot[domain=-2:2, smooth, rotate=\a] (\x,{\x*\x+1});
\draw[-latex, magenta, ultra thick, rotate=\a] (0,1)--(0,4); %This is changed to point same way as the fill
}
\end{scope}
\draw[magenta] (0,0) circle(1);
\draw[magenta] (0,0) circle(4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Circle diagram with filled areas and arrows]

Comment: Chapeau!(+1) But I dont see the difference from my code.

Comment: See edit - code comment

Comment: Ok, I see at last (I am 75 y old!). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

With

```
\foreach \a in {45}{
                \draw[cyan,fill] plot[domain=-2:2,smooth,rotate=\a] (\x,{\x*\x+1});
                \draw[-latex,magenta,line width=2pt,rotate=\a] (1,0)--(4,0);
                }
```

[image]

With

```
\foreach \a in {45}{
            \draw[cyan,fill] plot[domain=-2:2,smooth,rotate=-90+\a] (\x,{\x*\x+1});
            \draw[-latex,magenta,line width=2pt,rotate=\a] (1,0)--(4,0);
            }
```

[image]

**The complete code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \draw[gray!20,dashed] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
        \draw[-latex] (-4.2,0)--(4.3,0) node[right] () {\footnotesize $x$};
        \foreach \i in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
            \draw (\i,-0)--(\i,-0.1) node[below] () {\footnotesize \i};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-4.2)--(0,4.3) node[above] () {\footnotesize $y$};
        \foreach \i in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
            \draw (0,\i)--(-.1,\i) node[left] () {\footnotesize \i};
        \draw (-.2,-.2) node () {\footnotesize $O$};
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) circle(4);
            \foreach \a in {45,135,225,315}{
            \draw[cyan,fill] plot[domain=-2:2,smooth,rotate=-90+\a] (\x,{\x*\x+1});
            \draw[-latex,magenta,line width=2pt,rotate=\a] (1,0)--(4,0);
            }
        \end{scope}
        \draw[magenta] (0,0) circle(1);
        \draw[magenta] (0,0) circle(4);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't really like the following solution, but it looks like @JasperHabicht is right about the clipping as a side effect:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \draw[gray!20,dashed] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
        \draw[-latex] (-4.2,0)--(4.3,0) node[right] () {\footnotesize $x$};
        \foreach \i in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
            \draw (\i,-0)--(\i,-0.1) node[below] () {\footnotesize \i};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-4.2)--(0,4.3) node[above] () {\footnotesize $y$};
        \foreach \i in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
            \draw (0,\i)--(-.1,\i) node[left] () {\footnotesize \i};
        \draw (-.2,-.2) node () {\footnotesize $O$};
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) circle(4);
            \foreach \a in {45,135,225,315}{
            \draw[cyan,fill] plot[domain=-2:2,smooth,rotate=\a] (\x,{\x*\x+1});
            }
            \foreach \a in {45,135,225,315}{
            \draw[-latex,magenta,line width=2pt,rotate=\a] (1,0)--(4,0);
            }
        \end{scope}
        \draw[magenta] (0,0) circle(1);
        \draw[magenta] (0,0) circle(4);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes this solution works but not explain, as You think, where my code is not correct! (+1 for your work).

Comment: I just saw that my solution was working, but I have no clue why so I cannot really explain it (I never dove into the tikz package).

Comment: Yes You are right. My English is not.